# Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null flutter problem

Tags: flutter, dart

In order to get data from firestore database to display it..I've created a fetchHerbsProductData() using provider for state management as shown bellow:

```
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:food_deliv/model/product_model.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  List<ProductModel> herbsProductList = [];
  ProductModel? productModel;

 


  Future<void>  fetchHerbsProductData() async{
      try {

  List<ProductModel> newHerbsList = [];
 QuerySnapshot value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("HerbsProduct").get();
     value.docs.forEach(
       (element) {
        productModel = ProductModel(
          productImage: element.get("productImage"),
          productName: element.get("productName"),
          ProductPrice: element.get("productPrice"),
        );
        newHerbsList.add(productModel!);
     }
     );
     herbsProductList = newHerbsList;
     notifyListeners();
        
      } catch (e) {
        print("Opps, an Error has occured, please try again!");
      }


  }

    List<ProductModel> get getHerbsProductList{
   return herbsProductList;
 }



  }
```

than, in home screen I called the method using provider as shown bellow:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_deliv/providers/product_provider.dart';
import 'package:food_deliv/screens/search/search.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '/screens/home/singal_dart.dart';
import '../config/colors.dart';
import '/screens/product_overview/product_overview.dart';
import '/screens/home/drawer_side.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
   ProductProvider? productProvider;
    Widget _buildHerbsProduct(context){
      
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
               Padding(
        
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                     child: Row(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                       children: [
                         Text('Herbs Seasonings'),
                          Text('View All', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: Row(
                        
                          children: 
                                productProvider!.getHerbsProductList.map(
                                  (herbsProductData){
                            return SingalProduct(
                               onTap: (){
                                 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                   builder: (context)=> ProductOverview(
                                     productImage: herbsProductData.productImage,
                                     productName:herbsProductData.productName,
                                     productPrice: herbsProductData.ProductPrice,
                                   ),
                                   ),
                                   );
                               },
                               productImage: herbsProductData.productImage,
                               productName: herbsProductData.productName,
                               productPrice: herbsProductData.ProductPrice,
                               );      
                                }).toList(),
                          
                          
                            
                          
                      ),
                      
                    ),

        
                    ),
        ],
      );
    }

    Widget _buildFruitsProduct(context){

          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
                 Padding(
                     
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                     child: Row(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                       children: [
                         Text('Fresh Fruits'),
                          Text('View', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                   SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                             SingalProduct(
                               onTap: (){
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                   builder: (context)=> ProductOverview(
                                     productImage: 'https://h2.commercev3.net/cdn.gurneys.com/images/800/02165A.jpg',
                                     productName: 'Strawberry',
                                   )));
                               },
                               productImage: 'https://h2.commercev3.net/cdn.gurneys.com/images/800/02165A.jpg',
                               productName: 'Strawberry',
                             ),
                             SingalProduct(
                               onTap: (){
                                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                   builder: (context)=> ProductOverview(
                                     productImage: 'https://5.imimg.com/data5/BX/TP/MY-52486303/red-grapes-500x500.jpg',
                                     productName: 'Grapes',
                                   )));
                               },
                              productImage: 'https://5.imimg.com/data5/BX/TP/MY-52486303/red-grapes-500x500.jpg',
                               productName: 'Grapes',
                             ),
                              SingalProduct(
                                onTap: (){
                                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                   builder: (context)=> ProductOverview(
                                     productImage: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/single-watermelon-triangular-slice-isolated-white-background-as-package-design-element-78363100.jpg',
                                     productName: 'Water Melon',
                                   )));
                                },
                              productImage: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/single-watermelon-triangular-slice-isolated-white-background-as-package-design-element-78363100.jpg',
                               productName: 'Water Melon',
                             ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
            ],
          );
        


    }

   @override
    void  initState(){
      super.initState();
      ProductProvider  productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context, listen: false);
      productProvider.fetchHerbsProductData();
      }

      
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      productProvider = Provider.of(context);
       
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffcbcbcb),
               drawer: DrawerSide(),
               appBar: AppBar(
                 iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: textColor),
                backgroundColor:  Color(0xffd6b738),
                title: Text("Home", 
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 17,
                  ),
                  ),
                actions: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 20,
                    backgroundColor:primaryColor,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context)=> Search()));
                      },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search,
                       size: 25, 
                       color: textColor
                    ),
                       ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5,),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 20,
                      backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                      child: Icon(Icons.shop, size: 25, color: Colors.black,),
                    ),
                  ),
                ], 
               ),
               body: ListView(
                 children: [
                   Padding(
                     padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                     child: Container(
                       height: 200,
                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         image: DecorationImage(
                           fit: BoxFit.cover,
                           image: AssetImage('assets/1.jpg'),
                
                           ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      
                       ),
                       child: Row(
                         children: [
                           Expanded(
                             flex:1,
                             child: Container(
                            
                               child: Column(
                                
                                 children: [
                                   Padding(
                                     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                       right: 120,
                                       bottom: 10
                                     ),
                                     child: Container(
                                     height: 50,
                                     width: 100,
                                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                       color: Color(0xffd1ad17),
                                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                         bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
                                         bottomLeft:  Radius.circular(50),
                                       ),
                                     ),  
                                     child: Center(
                                       child: Text('Vegi', style: TextStyle(
                                         color: Colors.white,
                                         fontSize: 25,
                                         shadows: [
                                           BoxShadow(
                                             color: Colors.green,
                                               blurRadius: 12,
                                               offset: Offset(3, 3),
                                         ),
                                         ], 
                                       ),
                                       ),
                                     ),
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                   Text('30% Off', style: TextStyle(
                                     fontSize: 40,
                                     color: Colors.green[100],
                                     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                   ),
                                   ),
                                   Padding(
                                     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                     child: Text('On all vegetables products', 
                                     style: TextStyle(
                                       fontSize: 15,
                                       color: Colors.white,
                                  
                                     ),
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 ],
                               ),
                             ),
                             ),
                             Expanded(
                             child: Container(
                            
                             ),
                             ),
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                   
                    _buildHerbsProduct(context),
                     _buildFruitsProduct(context),
                 ],
               ) ,
    );
  }
}
```

I got the following problems in the debug console :

2
W/System  (26034): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(26034): Notifying id token listeners about user ( o9dkvdaJ1VSJyveWGGMV8BeZLKY2 ).
W/DynamiteModule(26034): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(26034): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(26034): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/TetheringManager(26034): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.vegi_delivery
2
I/e.vegi_deliver(26034): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto(26034): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 294 native methods...
W/e.vegi_deliver(26034): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller(26034): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/e.vegi_deliver(26034): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/e.vegi_deliver(26034): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/e.vegi_deliver(26034): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/e.vegi_deliver(26034): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/e.vegi_deliver(26034): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/e.vegi_deliver(26034): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/flutter (26034): Opps, an Error has occured, please try again!
W/e.vegi_deliver(26034): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
---end-------

In advance, Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the collections on the firebase data and added them back, also I had to delete the google account registration and register again.